# Django-REST-framework - forming endpoint/url for viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, view, router

api_urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('apps.accs.urls')),
]
```

apps.accs.urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', AccountViewSet, 'accounts')
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

models.py:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    pass

class TargetUser(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='target_users')
```

views.py:

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all()

    @detail_route(methods=['get', 'post'])
    def target_users(self, request, pk=None):
        account = self.get_object()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # here I'm creating the instance of TargetUser  

        elif request.method == 'GET':
            # here I'm getting the list of TargetUser instances
```

As per the code above I have the following urls:

`/accounts/` - here I get the list of accounts

`/accounts/{pk}/` - here I get the particular account

`/accounts/{pk}/target_users/` - if `GET`, I get the list of `TargetUser` instances, that belong to the particular account; if `POST`, I create the new `TargetUser` instance for particular account

The question is - how should I realize the following url -

`/accounts/{pk}/target_users/{user_pk}`

with possibility to `GET` and `DELETE` particular target user.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers)